# Could someone help me with this improper integral?

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals, gamma-function

The improper integral is
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{y^2-t^2}}\cdot\exp{\left[ -\frac{(x-t)^2}{A} \right]} ~\mathrm{d}t = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left( y^2-t^2 \right)^{(-1/2)}\cdot\exp{\left( \frac{-x^2-t^2}{A} \right)} \cdot \exp(2xt/A) ~\mathrm{d}t
$$
and I want to simplify it.

I notice it's similar to the gamma function $\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{e}^{-t}t^{z-1} ~\mathrm{d}t$, but I can't handle the term $\exp(2xt/A)$.

Comment: Did you try for $x=y=A=1$ ?

Comment: It looks like a kind of Weierstrass transform. Are you sure it possesses a closed form ?

Comment: Mathematica can compute.

Comment: I‘m not sure. But my goal isn't to compute it. Turning it into a more concise form is also good. For example, can it be expressed using the gamma function, just like the beta function? @Abezhiko

Comment: Thank you. I'll try it. @MariuszIwaniuk